# How to bind Dictionary<string,.string> to XAML in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created in my viewmodel Dictionary<string, string>.

```
public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>> ObjectDetailsRows { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>();

public void SomeMethod()
{
  ...
  //add some items to a dictionary..
  ...
  OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjectDetailsRows));
}
```

On my XAML part Im trying to do this:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectDetailsRows}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Key}" Detail="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I can clearly see that I binded correctly my dictionary, I can see lines on my page (in emulator).

If I remove binding for example Key and put just `Text="some text"` it works and populates all 26 rows, based on provided dictionary (which has 26 objects).
But when I set just like this `Text="{Bindings Key}"` or `Text="{Bindings Value}"` it gives me nothing.

**UPDATE:**

```
 public class CustomPin : Pin
    {
        //string base64
        public string PinIcon { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public InfoBoxMapModel InfoBox { get; set; } = new InfoBoxMapModel();
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

 public class InfoBoxMapModel
    {
        //base64
        public string ImageString { get; set; }

        public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        public Dictionary<string, string> ItemsTest { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    }

        private async Task GetObjectInstancesList()
        {
            var objectsResponse = await ApiServiceProvider.GetObjectInstances();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                ListOfObjects = new ObservableCollection<CustomPin>();
                if (objectsResponse.Succeeded)
                {
                    foreach (var item in objectsResponse.ObjectInstances)
                    {
                        CustomPin pinData = new CustomPin();

                        pinData.Id = item.IdObjectInstance;
                        pinData.Label = item.ObjectClassName;
                        if (item.Points != null)
                        {
                            pinData.Position = new Position(item.Points.FirstOrDefault().Latitude, item.Points.FirstOrDefault().Longitude);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //add polygon
                        }
                        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
                       
                        foreach (var s in item.Strings)
                        {
                            pinData.InfoBox.ItemsTest.Add(s.ClassParameterName+id + ": ", s.StringValue);
                        }
                        foreach (var i in item.Integers)
                        {
                            if (i.IntValue.HasValue)
                            {
                                pinData.InfoBox.ItemsTest.Add(i.ClassParameterName+id +": ", i.IntValue.Value.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (var date in item.Dates.Take(1))
                        {
                            pinData.InfoBox.ItemsTest.Add(date.ClassParameterName + id + ": ", date.DateValue.ToString());
                        }
                       
                        ListOfObjects.Add(pinData);
                    }
                }

                TemporalData.ObjectsData = ListOfObjects;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListOfObjects));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TemporalData.ObjectsData));
            });
        }
```

Ive tried this xaml:

```
<ListView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObjects}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding InfoBox.ItemsTest}" Detail="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: you are using a `ObservableCollection<Dictionary<>>` but treating it like a `Dictionary<>` in the binding.  Get rid of the `ObservableCollection`

Comment: You mean to put `List<>` instead of `ObservableCollection`? Because I need a List of dictionaries. For each row in my page I will have one corresponding dictionary item from that list.

Comment: No.  A Dictionary is a Collection of objects, so if you want each row to be one item from the Dictionary, you don't need to wrap it any another collection.

Comment: @Jason you cant take a look on my updated question at the bottom. I now have my Dictionary in my model class. But still I cant access it. The faraway where I can reach it `text = "{Binding Binding InfoBox.ItemsTest}"` and Im getting this: https://i.imgur.com/l6y8Tmh.png

Comment: `ItemsTest` is a dictionary - how do you expect that to display in a `Label`?

Comment: Well I dont, I want to present ItemsTest.Key in a Label.

Comment: if there are 10 items in your Dictionary, and you have a single Label, how will that work?  Are you trying to create a nested list?

Comment: yes. Each item in my main list will have a dictionary (or collection). Why Im putting dictionary instead of list is that I need to separate into key,value pairs to add some font styling to the key part. Here is the example https://i.imgur.com/zzMrjpz.png

Comment: then you need to read the docs on grouping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance

Comment: I didnt find it useful in my case.

Comment: Don't bind to a Dictionary. I would recommend you to convert the dictionary to models and then bind to those models.